# how can i change rules of firebase?

Tags: java, firebase

A database that is constantly updated, and adds data on a daily basis ...
I was used  Firebase as a trial and I got a notification to the email asking me to protect the data or it will be deleted completely ...
Do I have to extend the time in the code below? if yes >>> how can i do it ?  For example to 2022? Or what should I do?
if i put the (false)  on writing and reading, it will continue to be updated by the users or will it stop? Thank you

```
 {
"rules": {
 ".read": "now < 1601240400000",  // 2020-9-28
 ".write": "now < 1601240400000",  // 2020-9-28
}
}
```